# How to call progress dialog in service from activivty

Tags: android, service, progressdialog

I want to have the progress dialog somewhere in my code of service class.
For this, I had looked over many solutions, but i didn't find any solution. 
Here this is what i  had tried..
For this I created an  inner interface in service class

```
 public  interface serviceObserver {
        public void startLoading();
        public void stopLoading();
    }
```

I had implemented this interface in my activity 
Where I had Overridden these methods

```
ProgressDialog dialog_Service;
  @Override
    public void startLoading() {
        dialog_Service= new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
        dialog_Service.setMessage("Auto Verifying Otp");
        dialog_Service.setCancelable(false);
        dialog_Service.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stopLoading() {
        dialog_Service= new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
            dialog_Service.cancel();
    }
```

In my service class, where I want to call these methods , I am calling like..

```
 serviceObserver aa = new SmsSendActivity();
                                aa.startLoading();
```

While running this I get error of NUllPOinterException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:200)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:196)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:141)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
        at com.Activities.SmsSendActivity.startLoading(SmsSendActivity.java:369)
        at com.Services.VerifyOtpService$1$1.run(VerifyOtpService.java:78)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6377)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem..?

Comment: Do you want to show progress dialog in your activity from service isn't it?

Comment: Yes , exactly. I am   auto Verifying the otp, and that is done in service  class. When i receive the otp, i want to show the progress dialog.

Comment: It returns the application context. I had tried putting Classname.this , but that also didn't help me. I am getting nullPointerExcepion

Comment: it returns the context of entire application. Do you have any way to fix this

Comment: Yes ,I know. Let me try.

Comment: It is returning null

Comment: So , what can i do, to get my desired output.

Comment: I had created a object of Context,..
 context= getApplicationContext();
i had used this in Oncreate method

Comment: actually , i am calling this method from a service class, in whichi had extended intentService class. Trought that, i want to show the progress dialog

Comment: Its IntentService Class

Comment: Tree is like IntentService -> Service ->ContextWrapper-> Context

Comment: Okk. Let me give it a try

Comment: While using this, it says android.app.IntentService is not an enclosing class

Comment: While passing context in constructor... which is as
dialog_Service= new ProgressDialog(IntentService.this);

Android Studio shows an error and error essage is  " android.app.IntentService is not an enclosing class"

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: Again NullPointerException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172928/discussion-between-tapesh-gupta-and-pskink).